# Hotkey on viewing docstring of function in PyDev?

Tags: python, eclipse, user-interface, pydev, docstring

In PyDev, when cursor hovers function name, tooltip with docstring text appears.

Is there way to assign a hotkey on this event, for viewing docstrings using only keyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no direct keyboard shortcut for this when working with PyDev. For JDT, CDT or PDT <kbd>F2</kbd> should work, but it does not in PyDev.

However, as an alternative, you can hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> which brings up the content assist, which will show the documentation right next to it.

Btw: the hover tooltip does not show the docstring only, but the whole content of a method.

Here is how the content assist should look like:

[image]

[python](/questions/tagged/python)[pydev](/questions/tagged/pydev)[eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse)[keyboard-shortcuts](/questions/tagged/keyboard-shortcuts)[docstring](/questions/tagged/docstring)